# how to put char * into array so that I can use it in qsort, and then move on to the next line

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

I have lineget function that returns `char *`(it detects `'\n'`) and `NULL` on `EOF`. 
In `main()` I'm trying to recognize particular words from that line.
I used strtok:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *line, *ptr;
    FILE *infile;
    FILE *outfile;
    char **helper = NULL;
    int strtoks = 0;
    void *temp;

    infile=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    outfile=fopen(argv[2],"w");

    while(((line=readline(infile))!=NULL))
    {
        ptr = strtok(line, " ");

        temp = realloc(helper, (strtoks)*sizeof(char *));
        if(temp == NULL) {
            printf("Bad alloc error\n");
            free(helper);
            return 0;
        } else {
            helper=temp;
        }
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            strtoks++;
            fputs(ptr, outfile);
            fputc(' ', outfile);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
            helper[strtoks-1] = ptr;
        }
        /*fputs(line, outfile);*/
        free(line);
    }
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I have no idea how to put every of tokenized words into an array (I created `char ** helper` for that purpose), so that it can be used in `qsort` like `qsort(helper, strtoks, sizeof(char*), compare_string);`.

Ad. 2 Even if it would work - I don't know how to clear that line, and proceed to sorting next one. How to do that?

I even crashed valgrind (with the code presented above) -> "valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal"

Where is the mistake ?

Comment: Is the function `lineget()` as in the opening spiel or `readline()` as in the code?

Comment: I'm fairly sure Peter means `readline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious problem (there may be others) is that you're reallocating helper to the value of strtoks at the beginning of the line, but then incrementing strtoks and adding to the array at higher values of strtoks.  For instance, on the first line, strtoks is 0, so `temp = realloc(helper, (strtoks)*sizeof(char *));` leaves helper as `NULL`, but then you try to add every word on that line to the helper array.

I'd suggest an entirely different approach which is conceptually simpler:

```
char buf[1000]; // or big enough to be bigger than any word you'll encounter
char ** helper;
int i, numwords;

while(!feof(infile)) { // most general way of testing if EOF is reached, since EOF 
                       // is just a macro and may not be machine-independent.
    for(i = 0; (ch = fgetc(infile)) != ' ' && ch != '\n'; i++) { 
        // get chars one at a time until we hit a space or a newline
        buf[i] = ch; // add char to buffer
    }
    buf[i + 1] = '\0' // terminate with null byte
    helper = realloc(++numwords * sizeof(char *)); // expand helper to fit one more word
    helper[numwords - 1] = strdup(buffer) // copy current contents of buffer to the just-created element of helper
}
```

I haven't tested this so let me know if it's not correct or there's anything you don't understand.  I've left out the opening and closing of files and the freeing at the end (remember you have to free every element of helper before you free helper itself).

Comment: I agree that the use of `realloc()` with 0 in `strtoks` is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: Chosen as best, although I decided to take completely another approach. Simple answer providing much information.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in `strtok`'s prototype:

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

...`str` is not `const`. What `strtok` actually does is replace found delimiters by null bytes (`\0`) into your `str` and return a pointer to the beginning of the token.

Per example:

```
char in[] = "foo bar baz";
char *toks[3];

toks[0] = strtok(in, " ");
toks[1] = strtok(NULL, " ");
toks[2] = strtok(NULL, " ");

printf("%p %s\n%p %s\n%p %s\n", toks[0], toks[0], toks[1], toks[1], 
                                toks[2], toks[2]);
printf("%p %s\n%p %s\n%p %s\n", &in[0], &in[0], &in[4], &in[4], 
                                &in[8], &in[8]);
```

Now look at the results:

```
0x7fffd537e870 foo
0x7fffd537e874 bar
0x7fffd537e878 baz
0x7fffd537e870 foo
0x7fffd537e874 bar
0x7fffd537e878 baz
```

As you can see, `toks[1]` and `&in[4]` point to the same location: the original `str` has been modified, and in reality all tokens in `toks` point to somewhere in `str`.

In your case your problem is that you free `line`:

```
free(line);
```

...invalidating all your pointers in `helper`. If you (or `qsort`) try to access `helper[0]` after freeing `line`, you end up accessing freed memory.

You should *copy* the tokens instead, e.g.:

```
ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
helper[strtoks-1] = malloc(strlen(ptr) + 1);
strcpy(helper[strtoks-1], ptr);
```

Obviously, you will need to free each element of `helper` afterwards (in addition to `helper` itself).

Comment: Thank You! Also tried this with strdup, but eventually decided to take another approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting a 'Bad alloc' error because:

```
char **helper = NULL;
int strtoks = 0;

...

while ((line = readline(infile)) != NULL)  /* Fewer, but sufficient, parentheses */
{
    ptr = strtok(line, " ");

    temp = realloc(helper, (strtoks)*sizeof(char *));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Bad alloc error\n");
        free(helper);
        return 0;
    }
```

This is because the value of `strtoks` is zero, so you are asking `realloc()` to free the memory pointed at by `helper` (which was itself a null pointer).  One outside chance is that your library crashes on `realloc(0, 0)`, which it shouldn't but it is a curious edge case that might have been overlooked.  The other possibility is that `realloc(0, 0)` returns a non-null pointer to 0 bytes of data which you are not allowed to dereference.  When your code dereferences it, it crashes.  Both returning NULL and returning non-NULL are allowed by the C standard; don't write code that crashes regardless of which behaviour `realloc()` shows.  (If your implementation of `realloc()` does not return a non-NULL pointer for `realloc(0, 0)`, then I'm suspicious that you aren't showing us exactly the code that managed to crash `valgrind` (which is a fair achievement — congratulations) because you aren't seeing the program terminate under control as it should if `realloc(0, 0)` returns NULL.)

You should be able to avoid that problem if you use:

```
    temp = realloc(helper, (strtoks+1) * sizeof(char *));
```

Don't forget to increment `strtoks` itself at some point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the reasons behind that critical error.